# Link for Custodian badge from Teams leads to nonexistent review queue

Tags: bug, review-queues, badges, stack-overflow-for-teams

I just earned a Custodian badge in a Team for reviewing in the Content Health review queue:

[image]

But clicking that link directs me to a nonexistent page, outside the Team: `https://stackoverflow.com/review/content-health/history`

[image]

Comment: You don't need to be signed in to see https://stackoverflow.com/review/content-health/stats

Comment: "Stack Moderators" - my curiosity is piqued!

Comment: @user17242583 It is a private Team that only moderators on the Stack Exchange network have access to. Unsurprisingly, issues relating to moderation of Stack Exchange sites are discussed: we have Q&A from moderators about how to handle specific issues/tasks in moderation, and we also occasionally have Q&A from staff asking for feedback/input or just announcing something for mod eyes only. We try to keep everything that we can public, but some questions about moderator-specific tools or actions can't be shared publicly without violating the Moderator Agreement.